# I can´t connect to a database through visual studio or my app, but i can connect wit mysql workbench

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When I try to connect to a remote database using visual studio 2019 or directly from a webapp I get the error:

```
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.)(Microsoft SQL server error:53).
```

The same error as if change the connection string to a dummy value like data source= asdf1234...

It is my first time actually hosting and connecting a web app to a server and a remote database so I'm guessing it's something really basic that I'm missing.

I've tried:

- Connecting from a web app already hosted (this one is just a basic insert into..) and does not work
- Directly from the "add sql server" option in the sql object explorer from visual studio 2019
- Using a diferent database server provider
- Locally hosting the web app.

The only way I could connect to it was with mysql workbench 8.0 and I think it's because here i'm specifying the port of the database server
Also when I try to specify it in the connection string it says "[InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18]" if I use a comma to separate the server and the port (server,port) and

```
"(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"
```

if I use a colon symbol (server:port).

I'm using plesk onyx and phpmyadmin with the hosting and database administration (both are remote).
The code is just a controller calling the function savedata

```
public static int SaveData(string sql)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return cnn.Execute(sql);
        }
    }
```

The function getconnectionstring it's just:

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionName= "Database")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;

    }
```

And the conection string it's defined like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=***.secureserver.net;Initial Catalog=ph16971171408_;User ID=***;Password=***" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: named pipes work only on localhost they are like sockets in linux can you show us the code,  ican't think of why you have a sql server message when you try to connect to mysql with help of the mysql connector

Comment: edit you post and try to format it. this is uneadable

Comment: I changed it a little, i hope it's more understandable.

Comment: that connection string is not for mysql, it is for sql server

Comment: see here https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/connect-to-mysql/

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you so much for the help.